# Running specific table only in large sql files

Tags: mysql

I have a very large sql file (14GB). Currently, i am not able to open this file on my browser or VS code because it is too huge, keeps crashing  and would take so long. However, there is a single table that i want in this huge sql file.

Is there a way of splitting the sql file to get the specific table that i am searching for ? Any helpful answer please ?

Comment: You can try various software to split large files. like 7z, zipping tool etc

Comment: Basically, an sql file is just plain text with the consecutive requests, depending on what does your script, you can split it manually with a text editor. We would need to know what does exactly this sql file (inserting data, also creating table structure, etc). Also, if you create it with PhpMyAdmin, there a are options to export partial data so that you can export in different files

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

Step 1: `grep ${YourTableName} -rni path/to/you/file`

In output you'll see string which is matching `${YourTableName}` and **line number**.

Step 2: `tail -25 path/to/you/file > path/to/your/fileChunk` (where `-25` must be replaced with number from grep command), now in file `path/to/your/fileChunk` you will have **at top** stuff related to your table.

Step 3 (optional): Your file `path/to/your/fileChunk` at top contains stuff related to your table but in the middle and in the bottom of file you may have stuff related to other tables so please repeat step 1 & 2 on file `path/to/your/fileChunk` and delete needless info.

PS: It's only idea how to split your huge file into chunks, but you have to adapt this commands to your values.

Comment: When i try the first step, it just shows `grep: warning: recursive search of stdin`